# Sentences are crossing the margin. Is there any solution?

Tags: margins, hyphenation, line, lettrine

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % main font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%% MARGIN %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,headheight=0mm,]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%%%%%%%%% LETTRINE %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\input Zallman.fd %http://ctan.forsale.plus/fonts/initials/Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}
%letterine setup
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{4}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{0.1}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLraise}{-0.07}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.8mm}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily\color{green!0!black}}
%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main Heading}
\lettrine{A}{nd} \blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[Zallman.fd](http://ctan.forsale.plus/fonts/initials/Zallman.fd)

Comment: Besides attending to hyphenation, as the answers suggest, you can improve matters by loading `microtype` and by adjusting the alignment of the lettrine using such parameters as `lhang` (see the documentation of `lettrine` and, for the principles involved, https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-4/fine-typography/raised-and-dropped-initials and https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-2/display-typography/display-margins-centering).

Comment: I know, \sloppy is a bad habit, but it always works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution here is usually to enforce the hyphenation of the faulty words.

Since you are using a blind text, some words are not properly hyphenated.

In your case, adding `\hyphenation{Do-nec}` to the preamble solves the problem (I don't know if that's the correct hyphenation, though).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % main font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%% MARGIN %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,headheight=0mm,]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%%%%%%%%% LETTRINE %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\hyphenation{Do-nec}% <--- HERE

\input Zallman.fd %http://ctan.forsale.plus/fonts/initials/Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}
%letterine setup
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{4}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{0.1}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLraise}{-0.07}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.8mm}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily\color{green!0!black}}
%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main Heading}
\lettrine{A}{nd} \blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23):

Adding `\usepackage[latin]{babel}` will also help in your case.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % main font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%% MARGIN %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,headheight=0mm,]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
%%%%%%%%% LETTRINE %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\input Zallman.fd %http://ctan.forsale.plus/fonts/initials/Zallman.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Zallman}{xl}{n}}
%letterine setup
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{4}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{0.1}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLraise}{-0.07}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.8mm}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily\color{green!0!black}}
%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Main Heading}
\lettrine{A}{nd} \blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: @bmv (+1) I didn't know there was a latin language for babel. Apparently my hyphenation was correct `:)`